# Javascript: find closest number

Tags: javascript

i would like to find rounded nearest number in javascript e.g.

10 --> 10

11 --> 10

12 --> 10

13 --> 15

16 --> 15

17 --> 15

18 --> 20

19 --> 20

20 --> 20

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Also, this isn't the "closest number," this is "rounding to the nearest multiple of 5." And you really think [this hasn't been asked before?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+round+to+nearest+5)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var multipleOfFive = Math.round(yourNumber / 5) * 5;
```