# regex to find beginning word and ending with digit

Tags: regex

List

-MEDICAL STUDENT - YEAR 1

-MEDICAL STUDENT

-MEDICAL STUDENT - YEAR 2

I am looking for regex which search for word only 'Medical Student'

Should return : MEDICAL STUDENT only from above list

I am looking for regex which search for word 'Medical Student' and word finishes with digit

should return : MEDICAL STUDENT - YEAR 1 and MEDICAL STUDENT - YEAR 2

Looking for regex which search for word 'Medical Student' into string

should return all above list

Comment: As you have been asked on [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10778027/242)... What have you tried?  If you show us your attempts to get this working yourself it makes us feel like we are helping you instead of doing your work for you.  See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page if you need guidance on how to write good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#
Only MEDICAL STUDENT , a line does not end in a digit, uses negative look behind

```
^.*?MEDICAL STUDENT.*?(?<!\d)$
```

MEDICAL STUDENT ends in a digit

```
^.*?MEDICAL STUDENT.*?\d$
```

Contains MEDICAL STUDENT

```
.*?MEDICAL STUDENT.*?
```

Make sure the Multiline and IgnoreCase option is on

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
```

Comment: Second condition work only when i removed $ sign, but first condition doesn't work, should return only medical student which doesn't end with number

Comment: also how i can do non case sensitive

Comment: 'c#', above condition return all from list. should only return which doesn't have digit at end